# What command(s) are ran when you right click on a text and click "open man page" in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I know it obviously does `man`, to show the request manual page. However, I wonder what it pipes the output to, because it shows the entire thing at once, but it starts from the beginning. I would love to be able to use that with any command in Terminal, the problem is that `less` doesn't show everything at once, and `cat` scrolls all the way down.

I tried looking around in Preferences, but I was not able to find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "shows the entire thing at once"? You can scroll up and down in both `less` and `man`. In fact, `less` achieves the same basic task as `man`. Just that you can use it for any file and not just man pages.

Comment: @Arc676, by "shows the entire thing at once" I mean that it shows the entire thing at once. If you `cat` a file, everything is output to the terminal, in `less`, you have to scroll up and down, this makes not able to search for strings (with command +f) that aren't seen on the screen.

And I am aware that `less` can be used outside of `man`, it's man that calls `less`, which I have changed to `cat`.

Comment: `man -P cat (MANPAGE)` will dump the entire manpage to stdout.  By default (without the `-P (program)` argument) it uses `less`.

Comment: @Kent I know that, but that scrolls all the way down. I want to dump the entire thing like with `cat`, but start reading from the begging, not in the end.

Comment: If you want to search for strings within a man page, press `/`, enter your search, then press enter. AFAIK there isn't a way to prevent output to `stdout` from going past the number of lines displayed. You can scroll though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

```
open x-man-page://$1
```

where you replace the `$1` with whatever you would pass to `man`.
This I learned from [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/06/24/launch-command-man-page-terminal-help-menu/) - although I can't find any decent documentation for this.